# How to know when a co-routine that is being implemented by multiple objects ended?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, coroutine

In a project that I am building in Unity I have a Master Class (LevelManager) who does: `EventManager.TriggerEvent ("Fade");`

The multiple objects that listen to the event trigger a co-routine for 1 second to "disappear" (they lower their alpha channel of color to 0).

What is the best way for the master who fired the Trigger to know that the objects have already disappeared?

Comment: You can add a flag in the class where the coroutine is.. `bool isCoroutineComplete = false` then when the coroutine has completed everything it has to do, set it to true

Comment: Mmm but How do you confírmame that everyone who listened the event finished their coroutine? Or i should suppose that if one listener finish the coroutine, everyone has done it too ?

Answer (score 0):

if it's for a fixed time, you can just wait one second before continuing, easily using an async void.

```
void Awake() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { CallAllCoroutines += TestA; }
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) { MassEventTest(); }
}   

public delegate void CastEvent();
public event CastEvent CallAllCoroutines;

async void MassEventTest() {
    Debug.Log("Invoking event");

    CallAllCoroutines();
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Debug.Log("Can continue");
}

void TestA() { StartCoroutine(TestCoroutine()); }

IEnumerator TestCoroutine() {
    Debug.Log("Starting Coroutine");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    Debug.Log("Ending Coroutine");
}
```

Otherwise, if you wanna stick with framerate behaviour, you'll need to hold a list of the affected entities(the ones for which the coroutine was triggered) and check for their state on a frame-rate basis.